# What is the proper way to sanitize a password?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, sanitization

How can I sanitize a string that receives a hash+random salt?

I can remove the white spaces, check the length and use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, but is it sufficient? The `filter_var` is really  useful but it can't help in this case, right?

Comment: Sanitize to prepare the string for what exactly?

Comment: in this case to check if the hash exists in the database

Comment: Sorry, not getting it. You just hash the input and check if the result exists in the database… What's there to sanitize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to put the variable in an SQL query, then you either need to call `mysqli_read_escape_string` or (even better!) use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

There's no other sanitization you *need* to do. However, if the value will be coming from freeform user input (e.g. a text box instead of a drop down menu) then you may also want to trim whitespace and lowercase it as a courtesy to the user (to correct accidental mistakes they might make). It really depends on the application.

Comment: You should not modify passwords in any way by trimming or lowercasing them. This only aids potential attackers.

Comment: @deceze: The title may say password, but the question says hash+salt. Granted, lowercasing the salt will break it, but I think you will agree that in general the idea is ok. And I did say "depending on the application", i.e. don't do it to people's names, but do it to credit card numbers.

Comment: can you not use a regular expression to also inforce odd characters?

Comment: Lowercasing or uppercasing the password is a very bad idea.  Trimming it is good, as it will only kill spaces/new lines/etc. at the beginning and end of the password.  There's a reason that a good password has upper and lowercase letters, it doubles number of potential character combinations needed to replicate the password.

Comment: @phoenx - Way more than doubles the possible combinations by the way, extra possible characters increase the combinations possible along an exponential scale.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you're receiving from an un-trusted source a hash (effectively random data) + salt (actually random data), and you want to 'sanitize' it?  There is probably a definition of sanity that applies (a data format like base64 encoding, a maximum / expected length), but I strongly suspect there is a functional security mistake in there somewhere.

Most notably, why are you accepting a hash+salt from an un-trusted source, rather than accepting a password and doing the transformation within your trusted environment?  Accepting a hash+salt from an un-trusted source probably turns them into plain-text equivalents (you lose the benefit you got from hashing and salting the original password).

Answer (score -1):

First validate that the password matches your given validation rules. You can use a regular expression for this. Often passwords may consistent of a-z, 0-9, perhaps some punctuation and must be within a certain length - say 6-12 characters. Use `preg_match()` to validate the string for its contents and length. Something like `preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{6,12}$/i',$pass)` might be a start.

Next you can hash the password. You may use the function `crypt()` to do so. This will create a one-way encrypted string that you can use to compare against later when the user attemps to authenticate.

Finally, to store the password, yes using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` will do the trick to prepare it for use in your SQL insert or update statement.

Comment: It should be noted that a strong password would include both lowercase and uppercase letters, as well as digits and a healthy selection of special characters like !@#$%^&*();:<>,.? to choose from. Also my impression is that it's best to make them at least 8 characters long at a minimum.

Comment: You should store the hash, not the password. -1 until you clarify that aspect.

Comment: @SyntaxError A strong password is not a password, it is a [passphrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passphrase).

Comment: Technically a passphrase can still be weak and a password can be strong but I agree in spirit as far as best practices go. My previous comment was from 5 years ago when the special characters method was more accepted but I recommend the correcthorsebatterystaple method these days. Also concerning the hash - not sure if you have enough rep to edit answers but that might be better than downvoting if you see instances where very old answers are unclear about dangerous practices. The user you're talking to hasn't been seen in a year for example.

Comment: @SyntaxError I've seen that is 5 years old, but an update can't hurt and yes, I have enough reputation to edit, but if I edit the post, the poster will learn nothing and could make the same mistake in the future. If he doesn't show up, I will edit it eventually.

Comment: Why allow some characters and not others? that will just annoy your users.